# How can I parse this json in android project

Tags: android, parsing

How can I parse this json in an android project?

```
{"code":200,"lang":"en-ru","**text**":["Лучше поздно, чем никогда"]}
```

I need only a part of `"**text**":["Лучше поздно, чем никогда"]`

Comment: The value of "text" is an array of size 1. Could you post your sample code?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject("{"code":200,"lang":"en-ru","text":"Лучше поздно, чем никогда"}");
String text = jObj.optString("text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check those links to understand the concept of JSON serialization/de-serialization

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html

And here are the 2 most famous library for handling JSON:

GSON

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

&

Jackson

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes